# No module named 'bs4' in Virtual Env

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm working in Python 3.4 When I run my Python file in the virtual env, it gives an ImportError: No module named 'bs4' even though I installed the module in the virtual env. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `pip install beautifulsoup4` in your virtual env? The package's name on pip is `beautofulsoup4`, not `bs4`.